# How to change the values of an NSString inside an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a mutable array of strings. For this example, let's say there are 2 strings in it.

The operation that I would like to do is take the first string and assign the value of the second string to it.

I was trying something like this:

```
- (void) someAction {
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: string1, string2, nil];
    NSString * firstString = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * secondString = [array objectAtIndex:1];
    firstString = secondString;
}
```

But this method doesn't seem to work. As after I log these two strings, they don't change after the operation.

Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change strings in an array like that.

The array contains pointers to the strings, and when you assign one string to another you are just swapping pointers around, not changing the string object that the array points to.

What you need to do to swap the string in the array is this:

```
- (void) someAction {
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: string1, string2, nil];
    NSString * secondString = [array objectAtIndex:1];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:secondString]; //replace first string with second string in the array
}
```

Comment: Either this either make strings also mutable

Comment: Yes, although using NSMutableStrings with the code he wrote also would't work for exactly the same reason. You'd have to write [string1 setString:string2] not string1 = string2.

Comment: Guys, thanks for you reply. It seems to be working this way. However, I have a problem. All the NSMutableStrings that I declare and create inside the .m file work properly and are shown in the NSLog. However, the ones that were declared in the .h file, don't work properly and when I want to check their value in NSLog they show as being (null).
What could be the problem?

Comment: Question retrieved. I figured it out. I didn't place the properties for those strings and didn't initialize them. But thanks for answering my first question!!

Comment: You don't need to use NSMutableStrings - that was for an alternative approach to the one in my answer. The solution above works with regular NSStrings.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted what you said. In any case it seems to work just fine with the MutableStrings. I think it shouldn't bring up any problems if I use them like that instead of regular NSStrings.

Comment: No, it won't cause problems, but MutableStrings are less efficient so you shouldn't use them unless you need them.

Comment: I tried using this technique, but I'm getting an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.  My array isn't created in the same method where I use this technique, but it is declared before my @implementation, so that should make it global on my .m file correct?  The string I'm adding to the array is passed into the method, and the debugger is showing it with the correct value, so I don't think that is the problem.  The array is shown with the correct number of objects, but each object is reported as "out of scope".  Do you have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used an NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray?

Comment: Nope, it's an NSMutableArray.

Comment: What was the unrecognised selector? If the replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: method was unrecognised then it's not an immutable array. Just because the property type is NSMutableArray doesn't mean the array is mutable - check that when it's constructed it's created as a mutable array, and that the property type is strong/retain and not copy.

Comment: Ahh, that's what it was.  It was set as a NSMutableArray in the properties and the declare at the top of the page, but in viewDidLoad I put some initial values in it, and I was using NSArray there. Changed it to NSMutableArray and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!